# Compiling in latex-suite halted with lualatex error with pattern not found

Tags: luatex, tikz-trees

So I'm getting this error after compiling a .tex file with an import

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing.force}
```

and compiling hitting `,ll` in vim's latex-suite.

```
Pattern not found: \Vn LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library
```

This error is is pretty baffling. I'm not sure how to check that latex-suite is looking for `lualatex` in the right place. If I run `lualatex` in the shell everything is fine.

Comment: Not a vim user, but it looks like [this page](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiler-rules.html) has pointers on configuring which engine the `\ll`command runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your `vimrc`. Open the file with `vim ~/.vimrc` and paste these contents:

```
" Compile with LuaLaTex by default for PDF       
-let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```